# Convert row list of strings to float in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a data frame where each line is a list like in the following image.

[image: The dataframe]

I am trying to convert each list for each row in float to make some calculations and graphs, but I am getting the

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Location'`

when I am using

```
df_float = map(float, df)
df_float = list(df_float)
df_float
```

This is what `.info()` returns:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 50 entries, 0 to 49
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------    --------------  ----- 
 0   Location  50 non-null     object
 1   DOY       50 non-null     object
 2   SOB       50 non-null     object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 1.3+ KB
```

**Update:22-06-2022**
I managed to make in int the `Location` and `DOY` columns which they are integers using the following:

```
from ast import literal_eval
df.DOY = df.DOY.str.replace("'", '').apply(literal_eval)
df.Location = df.Location.str.replace("'", '').apply(literal_eval)
```

The same approach does not work with decimal unfortunately, any idea of how to tackle this?

Comment: can try to do it through a loop? It will be long if there are many lines.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
df['Location'] = df['Location'].astype(float) #(or int)
```

before the code that maps, because as a string it's not castable I guess.

Have not run it, just offering a potential help.

Comment: Thank you @White_Sirilo but I get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df.Location = df.Location.apply(lambda x: [float(i) for i in x]) #or int
```

this will convert every string in the Location's lists to float

Comment: Thank you but I get the following message `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '['`